# Second bootstrap datepicker not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two datepickers with different Id's and only one is working with

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">From</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="peak_start_date_from" value="" id="start_datepicker" required>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Not working

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">From</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="peak_start_date_from" value="" id="peak_start_date_from" required>
                </div>
                </div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#peak_start_date_from').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Where is the first `datepicker()` call ?

Comment: @GGO at first code snippet its working fine

Comment: There is missing code. If  the datepicker of the div `#start_datepicker` works, where is his initialization ?

Comment: @GGO ok thanks I have looked into this and found its initialization. Now both are working fine